# Sum values from column in html

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hi I need to show sum of values from one column, but I add there rows dynamically after button click. For example i check row in first table, click button, that row go to second table and from this second table I need sum one column. this is how look my tables and I need sum the 'StandardPrice' and send it to `<p></p>`. First with data from database:

```
<?php
   echo "<table width=\"50%\" id=\"first\">";
   $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_hotel")
           or die("Could not connect");
   $query  = "SELECT ID_Room, Capacity, StandardPrice FROM Rooms"; 
   $result = mysqli_query($link, $query)
           or die("Query failed");

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<TR class=\"\" id=pokoj".$row["ID_Room"]." name=pokoj".$row["ID_Room"].">
         <TD>" . $row["ID_Room"] .
         "</TD><TD>Osoby: " . $row["Capacity"] .
         "</TD><TD>Cena: " . $row["StandardPrice"] .
         "</TD></TR>\n";
         }

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($link);
echo "</table>";
?>
```

And second is simple empty html table:

```
<table width='50%' id="second">
</table>
```

Also there is my jQuery code to take row from one to another:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#addElements").click(function(){
    console.log("event");
    $("#first tr").filter(".selected").each(function( index ){
        $("#second").append("<tr>" + $(this).html() + "</tr>");
        $(this).empty();
    });
});
$("#first td").click(function(){
    if( $(this).parent().hasClass( "selected" ) ){
          $(this).parent().removeClass("selected");
    }
    else{
        $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
    }
});
});
```

So can You tell me how to sum standardprice column from second table and save it to `<p></p>` or `<div></div>` or perfect it would be to php variable or `<input type="text">`?

Comment: Show us the resulting markup please. The stuff that the PHP is rendering.

Comment: Use `each`: `var sum; $('span').each(function() { sum += ... })`

Comment: The 'dostepne pokoje' is first table and 'wybrane pokoje' is second. http://screenshooter.net/100857268/cpuqbbj i need to sum column cena from second table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you need to select each 3rd column, which can be done using `#second td:nth-child(3)`. second, you need to trim the `Cena:` from each value using `.replace('Cena: ','')`, and then using `parseInt()` to caste value to an integer. third, sum the values and display the result.

```
var sum = 0;
$("#second td:nth-child(3)").each(function(){
    sum += parseInt($(this).text().replace('Cena: ',''));
});
$("#yourDesiredElement").html(sum);
```

this would be placed inside your `$("#first tr").filter(".selected").each(function( index ){` but after your `$("#second").append(`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call this function after adding a row. [0,1] means the very first and the next one would have a sum. you may change this according to which columns you want to add summation. 3 is the total number of the columns in the table.

```js
function addtfoot(tblname,cols,size){
 var colArray = new Array(size);
 $.each(cols,function(i,v){
  let sum = 0;
  let j = 1;
  $("[name='"+tblname+"'] tbody tr").each(function(index, value){
   sum = sum + +($(value).find("td:eq("+v+")").text());
   j++;
  });
   colArray[v] = sum;
 });
 
 HTMLstr = "<tfoot><tr class='w3-teal'>";
 $.each(colArray,function(i,v){
    if(v==null){v=""};
    HTMLstr = HTMLstr + "<td>" + v + "</td>";
 });
 HTMLstr = HTMLstr + "</tr></tfoot>";
 $("[name='"+tblname+"'] tfoot").remove();
 $("[name='"+tblname+"'] ").append(HTMLstr);
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<table name="tablename" class="w3-table-all w3-hoverable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <th>Col1</th>
  <th>Col2</th>
        <th>Col3</th>
    </tr>
 <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td>100</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>200</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button class="w3-button w3-margin w3-right w3-teal" onclick="addtfoot('tablename',[0,1],3);">Add Summation</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

put the value of standardPrice into a data attribute, something like:

```
echo "<TR class='' id='pokoj$row["ID_Room"]' name='pokoj$row["ID_Room"]'>
         <TD>$row["ID_Room"]</TD>
         <TD>Osoby: $row["Capacity"]</TD>
         <TD class="s-price" data-standard-price='$row["StandardPrice"]'>Cena: $row["StandardPrice"]</TD>
     </TR>\n";
```

then do this in jquery:

```
var sum = 0;
$( "td.s-price" ).each(function( index ) {
  sum += $( this ).data('standard-price');
});
alert(sum);
```